# SendKeys to Rich Text editor Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, sendkeys, rich-text-editor

I wonder if someone can help me out. I can't find a way to 'sendkeys' to a rich text editor (Description) on my app. The code is the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk6Xg.png

Comment: What does the actual DOM looks like? Where is your JAVA code? What have you tried and what are the specific errors you are getting?

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Can you update the question with relevant HTML, and code trials ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting for additional information by the OP, this is what I think is wrong with your Java code. I noticed that you highlighted what you think is the rich-text box you are trying to send key strokes to. However, that is most likely NOT the element that contains the text. Below that, you will see there is an `iframe`. Unless you switch to the specific iframe, you won't be able to interact with it. Once simple way to switch to an iframe is:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)); // New convention for setting explicit waits in Selenium
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); // Old convention equivalent to line above
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("WHATEVER"))); // You can also search by `By.xpath(...)` or some other acceptable criteria like CSS, name, etc.
```

Here the timeout duration is arbitrary. That might be much longer than what you need and it is not really that important for your issue. Play with the value until you find one that is better suited for your needs. Once you have successfully switched to the iframe, you should be able to send keystrokes to the element. One of the elements inside the `<html>` tag should be your target.

```
WebElement elementInsideIframe = driver.findElement(...);
elementInsideIframe.sendKeys("TEST 123ABC");
```

If you need to do anything else with the text area (like setting text to bold), I think the best way is to use JavaScript commands to that. This seems out of scope for this post. Lastly, once you are done setting the keys, ***YOU MUST SWITCH BACK TO PARENT FRAME!!!*** Failure to do this will cause Selenium code to fail to interact with components in the normal frame because it thinks it is still interacting with the iframe. The same goes with opening new tags and switching tags to interact with the contents there. For tags, you need so save Window handles and use those handles to switch back and forth. Again, out of scope for this discussion (but I want you to be aware of this since it seems you didn't know about iframes and how to switch to them).

```
driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
```

If you put these lines together and fill in the missing information to locate the iframe and text area for your application, it should work just fine. That is, considering that the rest of your code is correct (which we haven't seen yet).

Comment: It fails to switch to iframe.


WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("tinyMce1641927583407_ifr")));

Comment: That most likely means that the iframe wasn't available. It is hard to tell without seeing the behavior of the page. You need to update (edit) your post and add all the information that was previously requested. We are trying to help you going totally blind. These are hard problems to diagnose blindly.

Comment: This answer was perfecto. @MihaiNicorec try to use _`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@id, 'tinyMce') and contains(@id, 'ifr')]")));`_

Comment: Thanks @undetectedSelenium for the endorsement and upvote (I assume)

Comment: Bro you are king :)))))). It's working!!!
Thanks a lot.

But why it didn't work how I made?

Comment: I assume that this number "tinyMce1641927583407_ifr" between "tinyMce" and "ifr" is generated randomly?

Comment: @MihaiNicorec think of an iframe as a private container you need permission to interact with... So, once you are granted permission, you enter the container and you can't see what's outside. So you need to switch focus to it and then back to the parent frame when you are done. HOWEVER, if you try find element using browser's tools, you can find any element in the DOM because this sort of "parsing" doesn't require to abide by the same rules. Your solution was good for browser tools, not OK for specification web drivers must abide by.

Comment: @MihaiNicorec '_I assume that this number "tinyMce1641927583407_ifr" between "tinyMce" and "ifr" is generated randomly?_' I have seen this from time to time. For those cases, I try `contains()` and use the string identifier part that doesn't change. Sometimes, this is an issue because there is no guarantee those common parts will repeat in the DOM. It requires diligence and patience.

Answer (score 0):

That page contains an iframe, so you need to switch into the frame first before interacting with an element inside it. I see you're using TinyMCE... here's an example test that enters text inside the iframe of a TinyMCE editor using the [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) framework:

https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/test_tinymce.py

To run the example, call `pip install seleniumbase`, then run the example with `pytest`.

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase


class TinyMceTests(BaseCase):
    def test_tinymce(self):
        self.open("https://seleniumbase.io/tinymce/")
        self.wait_for_element("div.mce-container-body")
        self.click('span:contains("File")')
        self.click('span:contains("New document")')
        self.click('span:contains("Paragraph")')
        self.click('span:contains("Heading 2")')
        self.switch_to_frame("iframe")
        self.add_text("#tinymce", "Automate anything with SeleniumBase!\n")
        self.switch_to_default_content()
        self.click("button i.mce-i-image")
        self.type('input[aria-label="Width"].mce-textbox', "300")
        image_url = "https://seleniumbase.io/img/sb_logo_10.png"
        self.type("input.mce-textbox", image_url + "\n")
        self.switch_to_frame("iframe")
        self.click("h2")
        self.switch_to_default_content()
        self.post_message("Automate anything with SeleniumBase!")
        self.click('span:contains("File")')
        self.click('span:contains("Preview")')
        self.switch_to_frame('iframe[sandbox="allow-scripts"]')
        self.post_message("Learn SeleniumBase Today!")
```

Comment: This is a Selenium Java post, not Python.